# How do I get specific date information using a Calendar object in Java?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm currently trying to use a Calendar object in order to get information about the current date. Specifically, I need to know the day of the week, time (h/m/s), and AM/PM. I originally intended to use a Date object, but answers on other questions suggested that using Calendar would be better. However, from looking at the API, I'm unsure about how to get the individual pieces from the Calendar object.

Comment: calendarInstance.get(Calendar.DAY) would be an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

What's not clear about it? It's filled with examples. Here are a few of those you named:

```
System.out.println("DAY_OF_WEEK: " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html. Your link certainly helps.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: you're right, I've changed the link. Idea stays the same though.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Indeed it does. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> However, from looking at the API, I'm unsure about how to get the individual pieces from the Calendar object.

You use [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) with the relevant field, e.g.:

```
int months = yourCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

---

Having said that, I see people recommend [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) here on SO a **lot**, so if you're not tied to `Calendar` (and from your question it sounds as though you aren't), that may be worth a look. (I certainly plan to look at it the next time I'm doing date stuff in Java.)

Comment: Ah ok, understood. This makes it much simpler. I originally saw in the API that it was get(int field), so I was unsure about what to use for the field.

Comment: @Wolfram: Yeah, the `Calendar` object's API isn't great, particularly from a 2013 perspective (it was designed back when Java didn't have enums).